# Proving $A \cap C = B \cap C$, but $ A \neq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Identify a condition such that $A \cap C = B \cap C$ together with your condition implies $A=B$. Prove this implication. Show that your condition is necessary by finding an example where $A \cap C = B \cap C$, but $ A \neq B$

Edit: I've read the wrong proposition/definition. UGH! The question was probably about having sets being equal, not empty.

Now, suppose that $ A \neq B$... that would mean that $A$ isn't equal to $B$. So they are different sets, but $A \cap C = B \cap C$ are equal sets.

---

I'm lost on this. I need to find a condition, but where do I even start? These are my thoughts about the question so far.

We need to find a condition for $A \cap C = B \cap C$.

Proposition 3.1.12 states that if $A$ and $B$ are both empty sets, then $A =B$.

So $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are both empty sets which is why $A \cap C = B \cap C$.

It seems that there are empty sets everywhere because  proposition 3.1.12 claims that if $A$ and $B$ are empty set, then $A =B$. It's like there aren't any elements at all. There's nothing.

We need to find a condition that demonstrates that $A \cap C = B \cap C$ which are empty sets, but $A \neq B$ means that there are elements in $A$ and $B$.

How is this even possible?

$A \cap C$ by definition 3.2.1 is $[x: x: \in A \land x \in C]$

x belongs in A and x belongs in C.

$B \cap C$ by definition 3.2.1 is $[x: x: \in B \land x \in C]$

x belongs in B and x belongs in C

The only way I could think of is a contradiction to this... but that would mean that $A = B$ ... there are no elements in A and B, but $A \cap C \neq B \cap C$ means that there are elements. There may not be elements in A and B, but there are elements in C.

Comment: Comparing $A\cap C$ and $B \cap C$ can only give you information about points of $C$. This alone should give you the required condition.

Comment: there are elements in C... so... it could be that just because there are empty sets in $A=B$ doesn't mean that aren't any elements....so we need at least one point to have an element

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram where $A \cap C = B \cap C$, and figure out what other restriction you need to force $A = B$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** What happens if both $A=A\cap C$ and $B=B\cap C$? (Note that this generalizes the case of both $A$ and $B$ being empty.)

Comment: hmmm so $A= A \cap C$ means that there are no elements in A and no elements in $A \cap C$. $B = B \cap C$ means that there are no elements in B and there are no elements in $B \cap C$... empty elements everywhere!

Comment: @usukidoll It certainly doesn't mean there are no elements in $A$. Pick $A=B=C=\{1\}$, say.

Comment: @usukidoll: $C\cap C=C$. Does that mean that every set is empty?

Comment: $C \cap C = C$ 

hmmm $ C \cap C$ means x belongs to C and x belongs to C
but that $=$ throws everything off. unless... 
If I just look at the left side, there are elements in C

Comment: @usukidoll: Do you know what is the definition of an intersection?

Comment: Yes. 

The intersection of A and B, written $A \cap B$, is the set $A \cap B = [x: x \in A \land x \in B]$

Comment: Good. Now, do you know what is the necessary and sufficient condition for two sets to be equal?

Comment: definition 3.1.8 Let A and B be sets. Then A equals B, written A=B when both A⊆B and B⊆A. Thus the symbols A and B denote the same set

Comment: @usukidoll: Very good. Now prove that $C\cap C=C$.

Comment: $ C \cap C = [x: x \in C \land x \in C]$ means that x belongs to C and x belongs to C. 

So since they're equal ... through.. def 3.1.8 ...

written as $C \cap C = C$...

$C \cap C \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq C\cap C$

Comment: @usukidoll: Excellent. Is somewhere there we have that $C=\varnothing$? Now, what can we say when $A\cap C=A$?

Comment: that.. . $A \cap C = [x: x \in A \land x \in C]$... x belongs in A and x belongs in C. 

through def 3.1.8...$A \cap C =A$ ... $A \cap C \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A \cap C$

Comment: @usukidoll: Good. Now if $A=A\cap C$ and $B=B\cap C$, what can you say about $A$ and $B$ (assuming that $A\cap C=B\cap C$)?

Comment: $B = B \cap C$.......$ B \cap C = [x: x \in B \land x \in C]$ x belongs in B and x belongs to C. .......through def 3.1.8. $B \cap C =B$........ $B \cap C \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq B \cap C$......well they're NOT empty sets that's for sure. seems that everything is equal.

Comment: @usukidoll: So $A=B$. Now use the hint from the other answer to show that if either set is not a subset of $C$, then we cannot prove equality.

Comment: hmmm how do I do that? That would be that C doesn't belong to $A =B$........or $A \neq B$ means that they don't have the same sets... probably because there's a C in them?

Comment: @usukidoll: For one direction you have to show that if $A$ and $B$ satisfy the additional condition then having the same intersection with $C$ implies that they are equal; and on the other hand you need to find an example of $A,B$ and $C$ such that the additional conditions fails to hold, and $A\cap C=B\cap C$ but $A\neq B$.

Comment: the only thing I can think of at this point is that  $A \cap C = B \cap C$, but $A$ and $B$ have very different elements which is why they don't equal.

Comment: @usukidoll: Deal with each part separately. First find the condition, what can you say about the relation between $A$ and $C$ if $A\cap C=A$? Next prove that assuming this additional condition, the implication $A\cap C=B\cap C\implies A=B$ is true. And you have practically done that. Finally find $A,B$ and $C$ such that $A$ and $B$ don't satisfy the additional condition, $A\neq B$ and $A\cap C=B\cap C$. This example can be given such that $A,B,C\subseteq\{0,1\}$.

Comment: so there is a set of 0 and 1 ... or $A,B,C$ is the subset of the set [0,1] so A and B may not have those numbers. .. but C has all of them like C [0,1]  A [0] and B [1]

Comment: @usukidoll You've got the right idea. Now try extrapolating to larger sets.

Comment: like so let's say we have [0 1 2 3 4 5 ]....... A = [0 1 2 3], B = [4 5 ] and C = [ 0 1 2 3 4 5]... Set A only has numbers 0, 1, 2, 3. Set B only has 4 and 5. $A \neq B$. uh oh... I think $B \cap C$ and $A \cap C$ need the same values

Comment: let's try this again... C = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]... A = [ 1, 5, 10]... B = [1, 2, 5, 10]. Intersections mean something in common. so $A \cap C = [1, 5, 10]$ and $B \cap C =[1,5,10]$
$A \neq B$ because while A [1, 5, 10], B has [1,2, 5, 10]. 2 is not in set A, but it's in set B

Answer (score 1):

If $A \not\subset C$, then let $x \in A \setminus C$, and $B = A\setminus \{x\}$. Then you can see that $A\ne B$ and $A \cap C = B  \cap C$. Hence you must have $A \subset C$. By symmetry, we must have $B \subset C$. Combining shows that you need $(A \cup B) \subset C$.

Now suppose $(A \cup B) \subset C$. Then $A \cap C = A$ and $B \cap C = B$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for having

> $A \cap C = B \cap C$ but at the same time $A \neq B$

impose you that

> $A \cap C = \emptyset = B \cap C$

This does not imply that $A$ and $B$ are both *empty*.

Let $\quad C = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} : Even(x) \}$

and let $\quad A = \{ 1,3,5,7 \} \quad$ and let $\quad B = \{ 9,11,13,15 \}$.

Because both $A$ and $B$ do not contain *even* numbers, we have that :

> $A \cap C = \emptyset = B \cap C$

but $A \neq B$.